# Single echo statement displaying values in 2 lines

Tags: bash, shell, unix

The echo statement below is displaying values in 2 line instead of single line (Redirect File).

```
echo ">>"`date`": Value1: " $VAL1 "Value2:" $VAL2>>$RES_FILE
```

Actual Result:

```
>>Tue Dec 1 10:20:24 IST 2015: Value1:1 
Value2:2
```

Expected Result:

```
>>Tue Dec 1 10:20:24 IST 2015: Value1:1 Value2:2
```

Tell me whats wrong with the statement.

Comment: How are variables `$VAL1` and `$VAL2` being set? At the moment, it's impossible to reproduce your issue.

Comment: It is read from file using while

while IFS=, read -r VAL1 VAL2
#echo statement
done<$FILE

Comment: Since parameter expansion works, it looks like you are bash. If that's not correct, you can remove it.

Comment: Your result doesn't match your code; there is no space between `Value1:` and the actual value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no problem with your usage of `echo`. From your output, it looks like there's a newline in `VAL1`.

You try removing it:

```
VAL1="${VAL1//$'\n'}"
```

Comment: A contributing factor is that you are overriding `IFS` elsewhere. If you were not, this would be unnecessary (and without this detail, impossible to reproduce).

Comment: This is possibly the case, but there is no way to tell given the code he posted. A newline in unquoted expansion of `$VAL1` would just be removed as whitespace.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to modify VAL1, perhaps remove at point of use: `echo ">>$(date): Value1: ${VAL1//$'\n'} Value2: $VAL2" >>"$RES_FILE"`